# Concealed cistern leaking inside toilet bowl

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I have recently installed a concealed toilet from Grohe (model Grohe Solido - [manual here](https://www.betterbathrooms.com/files/PDF/BB/Grohe_Solido_5in1_Euro-Toilet_Set_39536000_Frame_Manual.pdf)).

After almost 4 months, I have noticed a yellow smudge inside the toilet and I paid more attention to how the toilet flushed. This happened one week ago and since then I have noticed that, after each flush, a decaying stream of water pours into the bow from the right hand side of the bowl.
The stream decays after about 15 minutes, but never completely dries out. The water loss is not really noticeable (maybe 1/2 liters per day?), but the problem is there and it could aggravate.

[image]

I have tried replacing the flushing mechanism (see above diagram). I suspect that the problem is either with gasket (2), which goes into the drain pipe and into the toilet, or that the floating part piston/gasket (1) does not correctly sit on the drain part (2). I have ruled out any overflow  of water as this happens when the water level is also low. I believe the problem is more likely to be caused by the floating device (1) as the stream of water is stronger after immediately flushing, and then gradually and slowly decays to an almost negligible smudge of tiny drops.

I have already called an experienced plumbing company, but they couldn't find out exactly what is causing the issue, after they themselves have tried multiple possibilities. They have recommended I take down the wall and allow them to further investigate, but that comes with high additional costs to just redo the damage to the floor and wall tiles in that area. Due to time and budget limitations, I can do that only in a few months.

I am essentially asking for some ideas on either how to debug and temporarily fix the problem.

Should I use some dyeing agent to check when exactly the water starts to leak by gradually filling the cistern manually?

Is it a good idea to try to add some sealing paste (like putty) above gasket (2) just to further rule that part out of the problem?

**NOTE**: the vendor, Grohe AG, is not able to offer support remotely - hence the need to fix this falls on my and a potential contractor's shoulders.

Comment: "I have recently installed"... Have you contacted Grohe for some input direct from the manufacturer? It's possibly you got a bad unit and their warranty will cover replacement and whatever repairs are necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done that. I will see how far they are willing to go with this case.

Comment: At a minimum, they'll walk you through the trouble shooting to determine if it's an installation issue or a parts issue.

Comment: They replied. They claim they cannot remotely help and suggested I call a technician, which I already did. It's perhaps a bit disappointing.